# Why is the address different when it's on the same list?

Tags: c, list, dataframe, memory-address

My code has one `array`.

Why did the address of the `array` change?

Here's the code to create a sample dataset:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 50
float sum(float [], int);
float input[MAX_SIZE], answer;
int i;

void main(void){
    for(i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
        input[i] = i;
    }      
    printf("address of input = %p\n", input);
    sum(input, MAX_SIZE);   
}

float sum(float list[], int n){
    printf("value of list = %p\n", list);
    printf("address of list = %p\n\n", &list);//error. diffrent address
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the sample dataset:

```
address of input = 004070A0
value of list = 004070A0  
address of list = 0061FF00
```

Here's the desired result:

- I want the first `list` address and the second `list` address of the
  function to be the same.
- Because they think they're pointing to the same `list` of addresses.

Notes about the real dataset:

- You don't have to worry about the size of MAX_SIZE.
- This code was created through visual studio code.
- This code is C language.

[This question](https://itdexter.tistory.com/437)explains that the address in the `list` and the address in the `&list` are the same, but my code is not the same.

Comment: Given `int i; int* p1 = &i; int* p2 = &i;`, would you expect `&p1` and `&p2` to be equal?

Answer (score 1):

`input` is an array. When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof`, as the operand of unary `&`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Therefore, in `sum(input, MAX_SIZE)`, the first argument is a pointer to `input[0]`.

`float sum(float list[], int n)` declares a function with two parameters. `float list[]` nominally declares an array. However, parameters declared as arrays are automatically adjusted to be pointers. Therefore, this declaration is equivalent to `float sum(float *list, int n)`, and `list` is a pointer.

When a function is called, its parameters are distinct objects separate from the arguments. Each parameter is initialized with the argument value passed for it. Inside the function, `&list` produces the address of the parameter. It does not produce the value of the parameter, which would be the pointer to `input[0]`.